# How to 301 all urls except homepage and one other url to homepage in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server

I've recently reduced a site from a huge wordpress blog to a single page (homepage) and one other page.

I'd like to 301 redirect all pages which aren't the homepage or `/confirmed` to the homepage. I've tried a few things, but they all end in a redirect loop. Here is what I have in my conf.

Thanks for the help!

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php?$args;
}

location /confirmed {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /confirm-user.php?$args;
}
```

With this config, all other urls are going to the homepage, but it's not a 301.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do your bidding:

```
    location ~ "^/$" {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ "^/confirmed$" {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /confirm-user.php?$args;
    }

    location / {
            return 301 /index.php;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location = /confirmed {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /confirm-user.php?$args;
}

location / {
    return 301 /;
}
```

First `location` matches the root path and only root path.

Second block matches the `/confirmed` and only `/confirmed`.

Last `location` matches all other URLs, triggering the redirect.

Further information can be found in nginx core module [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)